# Linear Operator on each channel of OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, image, opencv, matrix

What is the most efficient way to shift and scale (linear operation) each channel with different shift/scale values (floats) per channel?  The input image may be any data type, but the output matrix needs to be CV_32F.

I could write my own for loop to do this, similar to

```
out[i,j,k] = scale[i] * in[i,j,k] + shift[i]
```

, but I wonder if that would be slow compared to perhaps more optimized routines.  Scaler operations are supported, but over the entire image, so I don't know how to isolate a given channel for this.  I looked at [split](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=split#split), but the docs don't mention whether memory is copied or not.  If it is, it's sure to be slower.  There are routines for color conversion, which is similar, but of course only specific conversions are supported.

Might there be some way, similar to

```
out.channels[i] = scale[i] * in.channels[i] + shift[i]
```

Preferably, I'd like to skip creating an intermediate matrix.